# JQuery When I click I get an error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console

I wrote JQuery to click on another element when I clicking on one element but I get an error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
What can I do?
Here my code:

```
<div class="outer-details">   
<div class="details" >
   <button class="btn" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" >       
</button>

</div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
<script>
$('.outer-details').on({
    click: function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.stopPropagation();
        $this.find('#dropdownMenu1').trigger("click");

    }
});
```

but I get in the console error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
What to do? 
Thanks

Comment: See related questions on right side !

Answer (score 0):

You need to [stop the immediate propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) on click of inner element:

```
$('#dropdownMenu1').click(function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   //rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution but it's not working yet

Answer (score 0):

When the click of the `dropdownmenu` is triggered, it keeps happening recursively.

You need to trigger the `dropdownmenu` click only if the click happened somewhere else.

```js
$('.outer-details').on({
  click: function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
      $target = $(e.target);
    snippet.log('clicked: ' + e.target)
    if ($target.is('.dropdownMenu1')) {
      //do something when button is clicked
      snippet.log('inside button');
    } else {
      $this.find('.dropdownMenu1').trigger("click");
      snippet.log('outside button');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.outer-details .details {
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-details">
  <div class="details">
    <button class="btn dropdownMenu1" type="button">menu</button>
  </div>
</div>
```